# Spring annotations for service layer and db layer

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Is this good practice to mark service class with annotation `@service` and `@repository` , since I am doing most of my DB operations in my service class. Does spring treats them a singleton class or prototype?

Answer (score 0):

It makes easier for Spring to target pointcuts with more specific annotations. So, you should code DB operations in DAO layer and annotate it with `@Repository` as it causes exceptions to be wrapped up as `DataAccessExceptions`. Also, coding related stuff in it's own layer give rise to code modularity and reuse.

Moreover using the specialized annotations help to clearly demarcate application layers, in a standard 3 tier application.

**Does spring treats them a singleton class or prototype?**

By default all beans are of Singleton scope in Spring. To make it serve as prototype you have to change the scope of bean.